# Special select query is not working in my spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

**Repository** Class:

```java
@Repository // This my architecture repository class.
public class UserRepositoryImp implements UserRepository {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryImp(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
    
    private static final String MY_SQL_COUNT_EMAIL = 
            "SELECT count(e) FROM User e WHERE e.email=:email "; // This is hibernate query. 

    @Override
    public Integer getCountByEmail(String email) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        TypedQuery<Integer> query = session.createQuery(MY_SQL_COUNT_EMAIL, null);
        query.setParameter("email", email); // This is return count in database check database
        // .. if you email this database passing already exist this email but your count zero created new email.
        return query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

**Service** Class:

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {

    @Autowired 
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User validateUser(String email, String password) throws EtAuthException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public User registerUser(User user) throws EtAuthException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2, 6} $ "); // This regex.
        if (pattern.matcher(user.getEmail()).matches()) {
            throw new EtAuthException("Invalid email format"); // This is check email regex.
        }
        Integer count = userRepository.getCountByEmail(user.getEmail()); // This is my method
        // .. count email in database and repository methods
        if (count > 0) {
            throw new EtAuthException("Email already in use");
        }
        Integer userId = userRepository.create(user);

        return userRepository.findById(userId);
    }
}
```

**Postman** Error:

> Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)"
> because "resultClass" is null"

**Problem:**

My problem is actually. I want to write a query to hibernated but for some reason it doesn't work. For such operations in spring boot, ie typing a query, for example polling email, put delete add and updated, how do I do it? I need to query me. I can't solve this problem.

Comment: the error you pasted doesn't seem to be related to the code you pasted. Can you show the complete stacktrace?

Comment: well now I'll give you the full code

Comment: Please write as the answer code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `executeUpdate()` for a select query. Try using `getSingleResult()` instead.

```java
@Override
public long getCountByEmail(String email) {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    String query = "SELECT count(e) FROM User e WHERE e.email = :email";
    TypedQuery<Long> typedQuery = session.createQuery(query, Long.class);
    typedQuery.setParameter("email", email);
    return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
}
```

`OR`

```java
@Override
public long getCountByEmail(String email) {
    String query = "SELECT count(e) FROM User e WHERE e.email = :email";
    TypedQuery<Long> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, Long.class);
    typedQuery.setParameter("email", email);
    return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me so much